# How can I give page content a fixed width and center it on large screens, and shrink its background image for smaller screens?

Tags: html, css

I just started developing a website targetting all mobiles, tablets and desktops using HTML5. Upon Googling I got to know that using the below tag would realign our site as needed for all form factors:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

So I just tried and seems like it works like a charm, but I see when we view this site on a desktop (with a 19" display) all the elements looks like they are dragged across the screen to make it fit 100% onto the screen and that looks a bit odd for me.

So is there any option like to center out the main content (with a fixed width) of the website with a background image spanned across all the screen when viewed on a desktop, but shrink the background image when seen on a screen with a smaller form factor.

For a live example if we see Twitter, it behaves the way I am suggesting, centering out the main content with a background image and as we reduce the size of the screen it shrinks the background but tries to maintain the content size as is.

Can anyone suggest me if there are any new properties in HTML5 or CSS3 for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fluid Layout instead 
https://www.google.com/search?q=fluid+layout+examples

And if you want to make a site responsive, see [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at [Media Queries (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). Using them allows you to use different CSS rules depending on the screen resolution, the width of the viewport or even the orientation (landscape or portrait) of the screen.

Here is a minimal example:

```css
@media all {
    #wrapper {
        /* have some whitespace on the left and right */
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    /* on small screens, use the full width */
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

As you see it is clever to first define your general layout in `@media all { }` and then adapt the layout for smaller devices. To see some examples check out [mediaqueri.es](http://mediaqueri.es/)

Comment: You might want to define your general layout without any media query at all, so that older browsers which don't support media queries (i.e. IE 8 and earlier) still see the CSS.

Comment: Thank you, was checking all things regarding media queries and looks like this works but i am not sure how we can know or specify correct pixel sizes for each screen widths on different mobiles/desktops, Also i see that it makes a bit heavy to specify different pixel sizes if we are supporting a large number of form factors.... If possible can you please help me out an easy way to find out the max/min pixel widths for any screen

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to start this task from scratch, as there are so much problems and glitches which others already wasted their time on.

If you like the Twitter style, their layout & JS libraries are actually Open Source (called "Bootstrap"), so you can just profit of their solution: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/
(take a look at the examples to see if you like it)

I recently started a project with Bootstrap via the great Initialzr (http://www.initializr.com/)... their motto is "Start an HTML5 project in 15 seconds!", so maybe the right thing for you too? There are also a lot of other options if you think Bootstrap might be to heavy!